# Screen display won't turn on

Tags: graphics, wubi, login-screen

I installed Ubuntu with wubi, using 30GB of space on my third hard drive on my desktop.
When I restarted my computer, I was shown the Windows Boot Manager. When I chose `Ubuntu` it made some noises (like bongos or something) but my screen went black. I tried restarting my computer, same thing. I have an `AMD Raedon 6550` graphics card and a `Dell 19" LCD Monitor`.

Comment: tried recovery mode?

Answer (score 1):

In the boot manager, see if you can boot into recovery mode, then try and run in safe graphics mode. Update the video drivers, then restart and see what happens.

Comment: I didn't see any options for recovery mode. EDIT: There was a menu option when I was scrolled over Windows 7 if I hit the TAB key, but I didn't explore further.

Comment: Right, the Wubi boot loader doesn't have the same options GRUB does... Hmm. I'm not sure. When you boot to that blank screen. are you able to get into a terminal view by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 or Any F keys from 1-6.